# How to sent / return values from dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {} to another page

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I have created a project that will retrieve the extracted JSON data and display it in UITableview. I don't want to burden the app by downloading everything. So, only when user selected a row, will it retrieve the employee details. I'm using a page view controller so that the user is able to navigate each page by sliding the page. **How can I sent the value I sent for page in dispatch_sync to detailviewcontroller page?**

This is my code from managePageviewController

```
func viewDetailViewController(index: Int) -> DetailViewController? {
    if let storyboard = storyboard,
        page = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {        

                let currentEmployee = employeeStore.searchEmployee[index]

                getJson().testsearchJSON(currentEmployee.id, handler: {(employeeDetails) -> Void in
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        page.employee = employeeDetails
                        page.employeeIndex = index
                        return page //fail here
                    })
                })
    }
    return nil
}
```

This is my getJSON().testSearchJSON fund

```
func testsearchJSON(id:String, handler: (Employee) -> Void) {
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: (favUrl + id))!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        //retrieve data successfully
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
                if data!.length > 0 && error == nil {

                    guard let name = json["firstName"] as? String,
                    let title = json["title"] as? String,
                    let id = json["id"]!,
                    let manager = json["managerName"] as? String,
                    let oa = json["oa"] as? String,
                    let email = json["email"] as? String,
                    let department = json["department"] as? String,
                    let division = json["division"] as? String,
                    let company = json["company"] as? String
                    else {
                            return;
                    }
                    let newEmployee = Employee(id: String(id), name: name, title: title, manager: manager, oa: oa, email: email, department: department, division: division, company: company)

                    //test

                    handler(newEmployee)

                }
            } catch {
                print("Error with JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

This is my page for DetailviewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// MARK:- Propertise
@IBOutlet var employeePic: UIImageView! //employee picture
@IBOutlet var employeeName: UILabel! // name
@IBOutlet var employeeTitle: UILabel! //job title
@IBOutlet var dateCreated: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var managerName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var oaName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var departmentField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var divisionField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var companyField: UITextField!


var employee: Employee! {
    //add applicataion name
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = employee.name
    }
}
//current employee index
var employeeIndex: Int!

let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
    return formatter
}()

//MARK:- assign values
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    employeeName.text = employee.name
    employeeTitle.text = "( " + employee.title + " )"
    emailField.text = employee.email
    managerName.text = employee.manager
    dateCreated.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(employee.dateCreated)
    oaName.text = employee.oa
    departmentField.text = employee.department
    divisionField.text = employee.division
    companyField.text = employee.company

    //retrieve image
    employeePic.thumbnails()
    employeePic.image = UIImage(named: "Default Image")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is this case it would be better to write data fetching in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear function in DetailViewController. Something like that:

In MainViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    viewDetailViewController(index : indexPath.row, employee: employeeStore.searchEmployee[indexPath.row])
}

func viewDetailViewController(index: Int, employee: Employee) {
    let detailController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController 
    detailController.currentEmployee = employee
    // present/push/etc detail controller
    present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In DetailViewController:

```
var employee : Employee?
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let employee = currentEmployee {
        getJson().testsearchJSON(employee.id, handler: {(employeeDetails) -> Void in
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    //reload UI for employeeDetails
             })
        })
    }
}
```

Also you can use GCD to wait for block loading, for example GCD groups.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm using managePageViewController... is it possible to navigate through the page without passing through segue?

Comment: You are welcome :) Yes, it's possible. For UIPageViewController I've found this gist maybe it will help - https://gist.github.com/andreif/3bace9961c7e70995856. Also you can search by stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this

```
func viewDetailViewController(index: Int) -> DetailViewController? {
    if let storyboard = storyboard,
        page = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {        

                let currentEmployee = employeeStore.searchEmployee[index]

                getJson().testsearchJSON(currentEmployee.id, handler: {(employeeDetails) -> Void in
                        page.employee = employeeDetails
                        page.employeeIndex = index
                        return page //fail here
                })
    }
    return nil
}

func testsearchJSON(id:String, handler: (Employee) -> Void) {
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: (favUrl + id))!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        //retrieve data successfully
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
                if data!.length > 0 && error == nil {

                    guard let name = json["firstName"] as? String,
                    let title = json["title"] as? String,
                    let id = json["id"]!,
                    let manager = json["managerName"] as? String,
                    let oa = json["oa"] as? String,
                    let email = json["email"] as? String,
                    let department = json["department"] as? String,
                    let division = json["division"] as? String,
                    let company = json["company"] as? String
                    else {
                            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                            return;
                    }
                    let newEmployee = Employee(id: String(id), name: name, title: title, manager: manager, oa: oa, email: email, department: department, division: division, company: company)

                    //test

                    handler(newEmployee)
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                }
            } catch {
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                print("Error with JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
  }
}
```

Comment: the part of return page in GDC failed.

Comment: can you swap this lines                                                    handler(newEmployee)
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);